# how to make object to follow curve with bending rather than it staying rigid

Tags: animation, constraints, shape-keys

This may sound silly but I just to simply follow tutorials back before 2.7 and I simply added my curve and my object, in this case a icosphere elongated on one axis to make like a slug type shape. So I would simply make the ico follow the path and the ico would "bend" and the body would literally follow the path, bending and twisting and all, as simple as that. Now it was a while ago but I remember for certain I did not use any modifiers or soft bodies or stuff. simple follow path procedures.

Ever since 2.7 I have to create a curve, add the object, set the follow path and animate it, but now the object remains rigid, yes i can make the object pitch up and down and sideways as it follows the path but the body itself remains "rigid" rather than moving and molding to the path, does anyone know how to achieve this "organic" movement when following a path? and just to make sure I made myself clear and make sense...

like if I make a curve with a sharp u turn, and I create a straight rectangle to follow the path, at the U shaped corner, the rectangle will not just follow the path and pivot in a center point tilting as it follows the path, the straight rectangle should actually bend to create a U shaped rectanlge during that instant that it is in the corner, and then shape itself to whatever shape the curve follows up with after the U turn.

Comment: would you provide some image what you need. Is that u need a sphere to follow in u shape curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the Curve modifier. That will cause the mesh to distort to follow the curve. Don't forget to make sure the mesh and curve's origins are at the same location. Then animating it moving along the curve is as simple as animating it moving along the same axis the curve modifier is using.